# Extend Multiple Classes in Java while Retaining Functionality of each Class

Tags: java, selenium, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

I'm using `WebDriver` (`Selenium`) and I want to add custom methods to `WebDriver` such as `driver.performCustomAction()`.

Being that I could instantiate an instance of `FirefoxDriver` or `ChromeDriver` I cannot simply extend `FirefoxDriver` bec I would not be able to use the functionality with Chrome Driver.

Tech I could create a new class and pass an instance of `WebDriver` to the constructor (so it could be either FF or Chrome) but then I would be unable to perform all of the non custom actions of each class such as `findElements()`, `getText()` on the new object.

In other words, if my new class is called WrappedWebDriver and I instaniate a new instance of it as follows:

```
WebDriver FFDriver = new FirefoxDriver();
WrappedWebDriver WDriver = new WrappedWebDriver(FFDriver);
```

I will be able to call `WDriver.performCustomAction()` but I will not be able to call `WDriver.findElement()` or any of the other methods defined in the `FirefoxDriver` class (or the actions I could perform using `FFDriver` ).

How can I add new methods that apply to both `FirefoxDriver` and `ChromeDriver` without writing it twice while retaining all functionality of each respective class?

P.S: I know Java doesn't allow multiple inheritance is there some other way around it?

Comment: What about an interface?

Comment: Or a wrapper class that wraps both a FirefoxDriver and a ChromeDriver

Comment: How about you just write a new class `WrappedWebDriver` that implements the `WebDriver` interface, and takes a `WebDriver` in the constructor? You will have to implement the methods defined in the interface, but you will just call the driver that you passed in's method.

Comment: Some people use the decorator pattern in their wrappers, basically duplicating the methods you want like this one `public WebElement findElement(By by){return this.driver.findElement(by)}` If you implement the `WebDriver` interface it would force you to decorate the entire thing, but make your code programmed against that interface to still work. If that makes you sad, you could also make the `driver` publicly accessible with `wrappedWebDriver.getDriver().FindElement...`

Comment: Or you could use `C#` and just use extension methods :) IMO implementing the `WebDriver` interface and just forwarding all calls to the driver is the correct approach, even though it can feel like the code is excessive

Comment: Please read on composition vs aggregation and their differences also how interface could be used.  It will help with your problem at hand.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create Wrapper class which will hold instance of the Webdriver and you will wrap methods of webdriver which u want to support. You can do it for instance like this:

```
 public class WrappedWebDriver {

    public WebDriver driver;

    public WrappedWebDriver(WebDriver driver){
        this.driver = driver
    }

    public WebElement find(By by){
        //your customization code
        return driver.findElement(by);
    }

    public void setText(By by, String text){
        //your customization code
        driver.findElement(by).sendKeys(text)
    }

    public void performCustomAction(){
       //your customization code 
    }

}
```

You can customize Webdriver standard methods by adding some functionality in wrapped methods. By making driver public, you give user an option to choose beetween using standard driver methods or your customized methods.

There is nice and useful Wrapper API for selenium named Conductor. https://github.com/conductor-framework/conductor. There you can find more complex example how to wrap WebDriver.

Answer (score 0):

You perhaps need to be Extending `EventFiringWebDriver`. This class by its very behavior is composite in nature (Its created by taking a reference to an existing webdriver instance) and it was originally designed to be used for tapping into the before/after events of all webdriver originating actions. But it can very well suite your purpose.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.events.EventFiringWebDriver;

public class WrappedDriver extends EventFiringWebDriver {
    public WrappedDriver(WebDriver driver) {
        super(driver);
    }

    public void performCustomAction(){
        //your customization code 
    }
}
```

So in essence you first build a decorator that implements all the interfaces that an actual `RemoteWebDriver` sub-class would implement and then have your customized class extend the decorator. The decorator class here in this case is `EventFiringWebDriver`